# Insert Adsense code when word found

Tags: javascript, blogger, adsense

I am trying to show google ad in the middle of the post after a particular word found in my blog content. I run a blog in blogger. If my blog post contains this text - `<!-- adsense -->`, it should run adsense script and show ads after the text.

Comment: I could be wrong, but when I last used blogger (probably 6+ years ago by now) I did not have access to any of the code that was being executed on it. I believe in order to do this, you'll need to modify the server rendering code on it to kind of "pre-render", look for the word, insert the ads, then render the client. Like I said, I could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with javascript. Well, technically you could, but you are not allowed to insert the AdSense ad tag dynamically with a standard AdSense account, you have to use the given html tags. However, you could theoretically accomplish that by using server-side code, but remember to show the ad in a way in which people see that it is an ad. I also don't think it would be a good idea to insert it after a word but rather after a paragraph with an appropriate margin.